# Jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } - Trying to pass guid as parameter

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to pass guid to a function but it gives me error,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

```
var gg = "someGuid";     
var callFunction = "<tr class='MenuRow' onclick='myFunctionabc('" + gg + "')'></tr>"

function myFunctionabc(abcd){
    alert(abcd);
}
```

I am trying on Chrome, any clue ?

**Edit**

Sorry for some people who don't know what's GUID, its a number like this "0a6bb960-97c4-4099-8e0a-cc5cc81ed451"

Comment: are you adding the tr to a table

Comment: @RocketHazmat really ? by someGuid I meant GUID... which looks like this "0a6bb960-97c4-4099-8e0a-cc5cc81ed451"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape stating and closing quotes of `onclick=""`

```
var callFunction = "<tr class='MenuRow' onclick=\"myFunctionabc('" + gg + "')\"></tr>"
```