# Jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: - again

Tags: javascript

In reference to my question [Jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } - Trying to pass guid as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976735/jquery-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-trying-to-pass-guid-as-paramet)

I got 5 variables now and getting exception again after modifying the method, please help.

```
    var gID = "0a6bb960-97c4-4099-8e0a-cc5cc81ed451";
    var Urla = "http://asdlasdljasd.con/asdasd";
    var Urlb = "http://asdasdlasdljasd.con/asasddasd";
    var tit = "akasjd";
    var tit2 = "sfsdfsdf";

 "<tr class='Row' onclick=\"myFunctionabc('" + gID + "' , " + Urla + ", " + Urlb + ", " + tit + ", " + tit2 + ", " someParameter " )\">"

function myFunctionabc(gID, Urla, Urlb, tit, tit2 ,someParameter){
    alert(gID);
}
```

Comment: see the difference in these two params '" + gID + "' , " + Urla + "

Comment: Is your code all in a single `script` block? Because your `"<tr...` line is just a string and isn't doing anything

Comment: Make a working test case(e.x. in here http://jsfiddle.net), so we can make out how it is supposed to fail.

Comment: @Ignacio, see http://jsfiddle.net/rV9dR/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/M7csM/

```
var t = '<tr class="Row" onclick="myFunctionabc(' + gID + ' , ' + Urla + ', ' + Urlb + ', ' + tit + ', ' + tit2 + ', ' + someParameter + '  )">';
```